# How to add multiple splitpanel in using javafx netbeans

Tags: javafx, split, scenebuilder, splitpanel

This is horizontal split i used, i want 3 splits in horizontal.(one more in right side). I tried using empty split and added horizontal split upon it,but that didn't work
[image]

Comment: Add a `SplitPane` to into the right of the first `SplitPane`.

Comment: Just add another child to the `SplitPane`. Probably this is easier in the `Hierarchy` view at the bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

I added one empty split panel. After that added 3 horizontal split panels. Deleted every first anchor pane of the horizontal split panel. [Refer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/476gV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I am probably late to the party but adding a new split to a split pane is easy. Just add another container eg. an anchor pane to the split pane. The split pane adds another split.